# ImportXML / ImportHTML workaround with URL Tabs on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to do a spreadsheet using Google Sheets and the importxml/html function. However, I am not seeing a solution for the URL since it has tabs on a persistent URL: https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001CY2T&tab=3&InvestmentType=FE

My goal is to extract the tables of value & growth but not seeing a way to work around that. Only making it work on the main page of the URL: https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001CY2T which is data I don't intend to use.

I did try to importhtml with table selection, however not displaying any data when the first URL is used. Also did try importxml with both full Xpath and Xpath for the items I'm interested in and not working either...

Options used:

```
=importhtml("https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001CY2T&tab=3&InvestmentType=FE";"table";"2")

=importxml("https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001CY2T&tab=3&InvestmentType=FE";"//@html/body/div/sal-components-pillar-cards-process/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/sal-components-mip-style-measures/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/sal-components-mip-measures/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the table you are trying to fetch is controlled by Javascript which is out of hand when using IMPORTs in Google Sheets. Thus, the table can't be scraped.

You can check whether a website/table in a website is javascript controlled by doing this. Go click on the lock button on the left side of the address bar and click site settings, look for Javascript then block it. If you try and reload the website, You should notice a difference before blocking Javascript.

In this case, if you try it on your end, you will notice that after blocking Javascript on the website, you won't be able to see the tables anymore.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMPORT functions of google sheets are not able to handle JavaScript elements. if you disable JS you are left with (and only this can be imported):

[image]

Comment: Meeh... Yeah, that was what I was thinking since even using XML selectors no data was available... :( Thanks though!